# Updating a WinForm label value from code without buttons

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, label, windows-forms-designer

I have a simple question but I could not find a direct answer anywhere

I have a C# program which executes a counter after the user pushes a "start" button. So 1, 2, 3, etc but the increments are performed with casual different time durations, i.e.

> 1 -> [4 seconds after] 2 -> [7 seconds after] 3 -> etc

and checked in the program every millisecond

I wanted to put an indication on the GUI to let the user know about the number reached

[image: Counter]

I was thinking to obtain it using a label for the word "Counter:"

```
// CounterLabel
// 
this.CounterLabel.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)
    ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
this.CounterLabel.AutoSize = true;
this.CounterLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1090, 35);
this.CounterLabel.Name = "CounterLabel";
this.CounterLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(58, 17);
this.CounterLabel.TabIndex = 52;
this.CounterLabel.Text = "Counter:";
```

but then I have two questions:
1) do I need a read-only text box to host the changing number

```
// 
// CounterValue
//
this.CounterValue.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)
    ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
this.CounterValue.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
this.CounterValue.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1149, 32);
this.CounterValue.Name = "CounterValue";
this.CounterValue.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(84, 22);
this.CounterValue.TabIndex = 53;
this.CounterValue.ReadOnly = true;
//this.CounterValue.Text += this.GetCounterValue();
```

or there is a way to have it using only the label?
2) how to perform the control to see if we have to update the UI? I mean, the value to display is checked every msec and I want the interface to be updated every msec as well [without using an "update" button to ask to show the value reached]

Thanks in advance to those who will try to help

Comment: If text `Counter: 10` is ok, then label is enough control for the task. Check this link: [How to: Use a Background Worker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx)

Comment: @Fabio: thanks a lot for your suggestion, I didn't want to use a background worker for such task but I appreciated the suggestion

Comment: Background is mostly right approach for task where UI controls need to be updated from not UI threads. Background give a possibility to cancel a running task or some other staff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes, you would need read-only text box next to the label.

2) add a method to the form as follows:

```
void UpdateCounter()
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(UpdateCounter));
        return;
    }
    CounterValue.Text = Counter.ToString();
}
```

3) call this method everytime the counter is changed.

Or you could use a timer to call the UpdateCounter function.

Answer (score 1):

another option is to use timer control it will automatically changelable value

```
 timer1.star();
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Your code
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for showing me another possible approach, thanks really!